# How to build a token factory Dapp?

Tags: solidity, dapps

I got a ERC20 token Contract. I want to create a Dapp to make it easier for others to use it to create tokens. Are there anybody can help me to do that? I can pay for your helping. Pls leave your Telegram here.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think, you probably should try to use https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol. It's gas efficient way to clone a given smart contract.

Here is more detail about minimal proxy: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167

Comment: what is the goal of cloning existing contract ? is it to extending it's exesting functionality or other reason ?